# MySQL Select row with lowest value in column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table

```
+------+-----+-------+
| name | age | class |
+------+-----+-------+
| Ben  |   4 | B     |
| Alex |   7 | A     |
| Jim  |   3 | B     |
| Ben  |   5 | C     |
| Ben  |   2 | C     |
| Alex |   9 | A     |
+------+-----+-------+
```

I need a query so that I can select the person with the lowest age such that I get:

```
+------+-----+-------+
| name | age | class |
+------+-----+-------+
| Ben  |   2 | C     |
| Jim  |   3 | B     |
| Alex |   7 | A     |
+------+-----+-------+
```

I've been messing with various combinations or GROUP BYs and ORDER BYs and can't seem to get it right.

Also, the table consists of about 8 million records so performance is important.

Comment: Please post output of `describe table_name` where `table_name` is this table's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to select the minimum age per class:

```
select min(age) as age, class as class from t group by class
```

(Note: I am assuming you want the minimum age per class. I you want the minimum age per name, then replace `class` with `name` in the queries ...)

Then you have to join the result with your table to get the respective rows.
The full SQL would be

```
select t.* from t 
inner join
( 
  select min(age) as age, class as class from t group by class
) min_ages on t.age = min_ages.age and t.class = min_ages.class;
```

For optimal performance, make sure that `age` is indexed as well as `class` (or `name`, whichever you want in your `group by` expression).

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT name,age,class FROM table t1 
  JOIN
  (SELECT name,MIN(age)as minage FROM table GROUP BY name)t2
  ON t1.name=t2.name AND t1.age=t2.minage
```